# REST client that can consume any REST API run-time and persist the data creating new tables dynamically

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm looking for a solution with Spring / camel to consume multiple REST services during runtime and create tables to store the data from REST API and compare the data dynamically. I don't know the schema for JSON API in advance to generate the JAVA client classes to create JPA persistent entity classes during run time.

Comment: do you have a more specific question? is there a particular part of this that you are stuck on? I will tell you that, unless the API implements HATEOAS, and uses a standardized JSON format, what you want to do is virtually impossible.

Comment: @jjones I dont think all REST Url that i get would be implementing HATEOAS. I heard something like a dynamic schema with mongoose on mongo db. i was wondering if any solutions are available for this case.

Comment: If the APIs are not implementing HATEOAS, how do you intend to discover all available endpoints exposed by the APIs?

Comment: @jjones The APIs are from vendors that conforms to OData standards. I would like to give the REST link as an input field and would like to generate Java classes on submission like the JAXB for XML

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to think through this differently.  Id forget about Java class POJOs that you don't have and can't create since the class structure isn't known in advance.  So anything with POJO->Entity binding would be pretty useless.

One solution is to simply parse the xml or json body manually with en event-based parser (like SAX for XML) and simply build an SQL create string as you go through the document.  Your field and table names would correspond to the tags in the document.  Without access to an XSD or other structure description, no meta data is available for field lengths or types.  Make everything really long VARCHAR?  Also perhaps an XML or other kind of database might suite your problem domain better.  In any case, you could include such a thing right in your Camel route as a Processor that will process the body and create the necessary tables if they don't already exist.  You could even alter a table for lengths in the process when you have a field value that is longer than what's currently defined.